# Melt multiple columns in one

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to melt my pandas dataframe from this structure...

| Name | Color year 2020 | Color year 2019 | Size year 2020 | Size year 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | red | red | big | small |
| B | red | blue | big | medium |

... to this one.

| Name | Year | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | red | big |
| B | 2020 | red | big |
| A | 2019 | red | small |
| B | 2019 | blue | medium |

I tried to melt with

```py
df_melted = df.melt(
    id_vars=['Name', 'Color year 2020', 'Color year 2019'],
    value_vars=['Size year 2020', 'Size year 2019'],
    var_name='Year',
    value_name='Size')

df_final = df_melted.melt(
    id_vars=['Name', 'Year'],
    value_vars=['Color year 2020', 'Color year 2019'],
    var_name='Year',
    value_name='Color')
```

But it doesn't seem right... Is it possible to do it in one way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `wide_to_long`

```
out = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Color year ','Size year '],
                  i = 'Name', j ='Year',suffix = '\w+')
out.columns = out.columns.str.split().str[0]
out.reset_index(inplace=True)
out
Out[151]: 
  Name  Year Color    Size
0    A  2020   red     big
1    B  2020   red     big
2    A  2019   red   small
3    B  2019  blue  medium
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version of `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
out =  pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' year ', '')), 
                       ['Color', 'Size'], 'Name', 'Year').reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
  Name  Year Color    Size
0    A  2020   red     big
1    B  2020   red     big
2    A  2019   red   small
3    B  2019  blue  medium
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = 'Name', 
                names_to = ('.value', 'year'), 
                names_sep = ' year ')

  Name  year Color    Size
0    A  2020   red     big
1    B  2020   red     big
2    A  2019   red   small
3    B  2019  blue  medium
```

In the above solution, the `.value` determines which parts of the column labels remain as headers - the labels are split apart with the `names_sep`.